# List of hard coded string/enum used in Java package or source folder

Tags: java, testing, junit

Is there some test framework that provide some base code to write a test to verify if there is any duplicate string, for eg test that get all the hardcoded strings like in local variable/instance variables etc defined in the java files(Certain packages or source folder) compared against the defined constants. The purpose of this is not limited to just the check of duplicate string but also to get base for some architecture test like Constants defined in package A should not be used in certain packages.

Comment: Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could [edit], rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Comment: Having said that: of course you can use reflection, to load any class of a specific package; to then further inspect that class, to see if it contains constants for example. But you probably wouldn't be able to distinguish `private final static String CONST = "hard"` from `private final static String IMPORTED = TheConstants.CONSTS` (in case the compiler inlines the static variable here) for example. I think, in the end, you would be "fighting wind mills". Such a checking tool would be pretty complicated, and most likely not cover all cases. So you invest a lot of energy ...

Comment: Although this is not an improvement suggestion (which should be the only thing in a comment), Java auto intern compile-time constant strings anyway. (so `String a="x";String b="x";return a==b;` will return `true`)

Comment: ... into something that doesn't buy you too much. Rather spend that energy to educate your team members about this policy, and reward them for following it; and make it a priority to go after when doing code reviews ( there is still some merit of having joint code reviews, based on check lists for example)

Answer (score 1):

I think, this kind of testing will bring more confusion to the team, than good. Defining duplicated string literals as contants in a single place is basically good practice, but if you have only one usage of particular value it could be redundant. Moreover some of the teams prefer to store constant inside the class if it used in single class multiple times.

It's much better to use static code analysis tools such as [Sonar](https://www.sonarqube.org/), to figure out such stuff, it will highlight if you use some string literal  multiple times without defining it as a constant. Writing unit test for such task is basically possible, but not worth. If you ensure you want to do so, you need access source files and write a code to search for string literals enclosed with double quotes and check according your desire.

Hope it helps!

Comment: "...writecode to search for string literals..." This is basically, what Sonar does

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/) to find duplicate strings.

For constants which are defined in package A and should not be used in package B, I guess you are better off reducing the scope of the constants to private or package-private.